# Asignar roles dependiendo desde donde clickes

Tags: laravel

Me gustaría asignar roles dependiendo de que botón pinche el usuario:

[image: botones para redirigir]

Por ejemplo:
- si pincha en quiero ser Asesor, que redirija al formulario de registro de Laravel y le asigne el role de asesor.
- si el usuario pincha en quiero se Comprador, que redirija al formulario de registro de Laravel y le asigne el role de comprador.

Pero no sé cómo hacerlo. 
Tengo este código en mi 'RegisterController':

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
       //'password' => Hash::make($data['password']), //mutador en User model
        'password' => $data['password'],
        'surname1' => $data['surname1'],
        'surname2' => $data['surname2'],
        'comunidad_id' => $data['cbx_comunidad'],
        'provincia_id' => $data['cbx_provincia'],  
        'municipio_id' => $data['cbx_municipio'],
    ]);

    //dd(Request::url());
    // $user->assignRole('Asesor');
    //quiero asignar varios roles depende de el botón que clicken

    return $user;

}
```

Pero la ruta siempre es la misma "Register" no sé si habría que pasarle algún parámetro a las rutas... alguna ayuda?

por ahora, lo que he hecho es añadir un parámetro así, en el en la vista que llama a la vista 'register':

```
href="{{ route('register','Asesor') }}"
```

y en la vista 'register' lo recojo así y lo mando por post en un hidden:

```
<div class="form-group">
<?php
  $pos = strpos(Request::fullUrl(), '?');                       
  $cadena = substr (Request::fullUrl() , $pos+1, strlen(Request::fullUrl()) );                                                
?>
  <input type="hidden" name="role" id="role" value="{{ $cadena }}">
</div>
```

Luego en el controlador hago esto:

```
if ($data['role'] == 'Asesor=')
{
   $user->assignRole('Asesor');
}
return $user;
```

pero no sé si es la forma correcta de actuar.

Comment: ¿Cómo está definida la ruta?

Comment: Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');